# RewriteRule without changing the address in the browser

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make an address redirect to another one without actually changing the URL in the browser address bar.

User go to `/path/page.php` and see what is displayed on `/path/index.php`.

In the address bar the URL remains `/path/page.php`.

This is the code for the redirection:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule page.php index.php [NC]
```

I'm wondering if I need to use [P] for this task :/

Comment: I don’t see why this rule should cause an external redirect. Are there other rules that can get in conflict with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[P]** is a proxy flag, you need it only for silent redirection to another domain or web-server (in this case Apache works like HTTP proxy). In your case *page.php* and *index.php* reside on the same server, so **[P]** flag is useless.

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up :)

I'm trying to obtain that silent redirection to the same domain